# Does my Memory (RAM) socket type need to match my CPU (RAM) socket type?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I am currently trying to build a PC and Have found the hard drive that I want, but now as I look into the memory ((DDR3)) none of the memory I want matches the  CPU memory slot type of 1150; all of them saying they work for 1155 to 1156. Does that matter when buying memory or should I just focus on the DDR3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets 1150, 1155 and 1156 are not compliant with each other, at least they have different pin numbers.

I guess you are confused the RAM and Socket. Support for a specific CPU depends on the CHIPSET and the SOCKET and the support of the BIOS. If the BIOS doesn't list the CPU you cannot fit it.
So you can't even just look for a socket. So think about chipsets too.

As for RAM, also check for the compliance between types through the manual of chosen MB.